# EC2 Security Rule for Connecting to DB from PgAdmin?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, pgadmin

I can connect to my AWS EC2 database from SSH. Now I'm trying to connect to it from pgAdmin.

I've watched YouTube videos about it and read SO posts as well, but evidently I'm still missing something, as I am still getting:

[image]

Here's my rule:

[image]

I got the endpoint I'm using from the instances tab in Amazon RDS for my database:

[image]

I clicked the link under Security groups, here, to select the security group to add my rule to:

[image]

What did I leave out/miss/get wrong? Thanks in advance to all for any advice/thoughts/info.

Comment: Where are you running pgAdmin -- on an Amazon EC2 instance or on your own computer? Your RDS database is configured as "Publicly accessible = No", so you cannot connect to it from the Internet unless you use port forwarding.

Comment: Additionally the only port you appear to have open in the security group is 22.  PG runs on 5432 by default.

Comment: Thanks to both for fixing this! Also, a note to others - to get the port to change to 5432, I had to select PostgreSQL as the type in the Input Rule.